# How to hide sidebar preview (on the right) in Finder on El Capitan

Tags: finder, macos

I don't know since when, but I believe from some update of El Capitan, this annoying sidebar preview on the right comes up everytime I open a new Finder window.

If I hide it using the mouse, it stays hidden in the current window but re-appears when I open a new window.

The sidebar on the left is all fine, showing items as it does normally.

Logically speaking, when I have switched to the preview window option and I already see items at the top, why would I need a second one at the right?

I couldn't find anything on the internet, people are just talking about how to hide sidebar preview in the Preview app. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

The image is attached:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called **Preview**.

Type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to turn it either on or off.

Alternatively open Finder's **View** menu and select **Hide Preview** / **Show Preview**.

[image: Finder Hide Preview]

Answer (score 4):

The instructions provided by TechRaf only temporarily hide the preview panel.  If you want to permanently hide it, from a Finder window, select View | Show view options, then un-tick 'Show icon preview', then click 'Use as defaults'.  (Note that this will change *all* of your defaults to whatever settings are shown.)